# "For" loop with column names as index

Tags: r, for-loop

I would like to create a loop in which the index is given by the column names of a dataframe. The idea is to select one column at a time and create a map based on the data in that column. I need `i` being the column name, as it identifies the name of the variable and I'll use that as part of the title of the map. However, I do not seem to be able to associate my index `i` to the name of the column. My code goes as follows:

```
# random data
x <- rep(c("AT130", "DEA1A", "DEA2C", "SE125", "SE232"), 4)
y <- c(1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0 ,1, 0, 1, 0, 1)
z <- c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ,0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
w <- c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1 ,0, 1, 0, 1, 0)
d <- as.data.frame(cbind(x,y,z,w))
colnames(d) <- c("id", "typeA", "typeB", "typeC")


for (i in colnames(d[,2:ncol(d)])) {
var_to_map <- d[,c(1,i)]

## do stuff

}
```

I get the following error at the first line:

```
Error: Can't subset columns that don't exist.
x Columns `1`, `2`, and `3` don't exist.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

However, if I just run `colnames(d[,2:ncol(d)])`, it works properly

```
colnames(d[,2:ncol(d)])
 [1] "typeA"             "typeB"       "typeC"
```

I could find a workaround by using columns numbers to make it work, but I would like to keep the column names since I am printing (10+) maps within the loop and I am using   `i` to insert the title of the map each, as follows:

```
# I use geodata files from the library `Eurostat`.
geodata <- get_eurostat_geospatial(resolution = "60", nuts_level = "3", year = 2013)
 

for (i in colnames(d[,2:ncol(d)])) {

var_to_map <- d[,c(1,i)]

colnames(var_to_map)[1] <- "geo"
# Joining, by = "geo" 
map_data <- merge(var_to_map, geodata, by=c("geo"), all.y=T, all.x=T) 
## creating ranges

 map_data$cat <- with(map_data, cut(value, 
                                   breaks= qu <- unique(quantile(value, 
                                                                 probs=c(0, 0.2, 0.5, 0.8, 
                                                                         0.9, 0.95, 0.99, 1),
                                                                 na.rm=TRUE,  include.lowest=T )),
                                                        labels=qu[-1]),include.lowest=TRUE )

 # Map 
 print(ggplot(data=map_data) + geom_sf(aes(fill=cat),  size=.1) + 
        scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Darkred", na.value= "grey") + aes(geometry = geometry) +
        guides(fill = guide_legend(reverse=T, title = "Percentiles")) +
        labs(title = paste("The name of this graph is the column name", i) ## here is where I use the index
             )+ 
        theme_minimal() + theme(legend.position=c(.8,.6)) +
        coord_sf(xlim=c(-12,44), ylim=c(35,70)) +
        theme( axis.text.x=element_blank(), axis.text.y=element_blank())) 
 }
```

I could also use column numbers for `i` and create another object with column names to refer to when pasting the title of the map, but I am wondering why the above approach fails and what I could do to make it work in that setting.

Comment: In the label definition : ```labs(title = paste("The name of this graph is the column name", i) ## here is where I use the index )```

Comment: I am using the same code to plot but I am not plotting the same thing, as the column to be used for plotting changes with ```i``` . Maybe I can edit the question

Comment: `var_to_map <- d[,c(1,i)]` won't work if `i` is the column name (and not index)

Comment: indeed. is there a workaround within my framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In base R, you can either select the columns by position or by name, you can't combine them both in one command. If you use `dplyr::select` you can select columns by name and position in the same command.

So here are your options -

```
cols <- colnames(d)

for (i in cols[-1]) {
  #Select columns by position
  var_to_map <- d[,c(1,match(i, cols))]
  #OR select column by name
  var_to_map <- d[,c(cols[1],i)]
  #OR select column by position and name
  var_to_map <- dplyr::select(d, 1, i)
  #...rest of the code 
  #...rest of the code 
}
```

Comment: Thank you. While the other answer works too, this one is more straightforward. Last option is what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot going on in this question, but perhaps this minimal example will help:

```
library(tidyverse)
# random data
d <- data.frame(x = rep(c("AT130", "DEA1A", "DEA2C", "SE125", "SE232"), 4),
                y = sample(1:10, 20, replace = TRUE),
                z = sample(1:10, 20, replace = TRUE),
                w = sample(1:10, 20, replace = TRUE))
colnames(d) <- c("id", "typeA", "typeB", "typeC")

for (i in colnames(d[,2:ncol(d)])) {
  type <- ensym(i)
  p <- ggplot(d, aes(y = !!type, x = id, fill = id)) +
    geom_boxplot() +
    ggtitle(type)
  print(p)
}
```

Comment: Thank you. May you please help me understand what does ```ensym``` do? ```help()``` is not helping much

Comment: It relates to evaluation and quasi-quotation; there are a couple of chapters in Advanced R that explain everything in detail: https://adv-r.hadley.nz/quasiquotation.html. Basically, `ensym()` turns the text (e.g. typeA) into a symbol ("typeA"). You can then use the symbol in ggplot (e.g. `ggtitle(ensym(i))`) or use the bangbang (`!!`) operator to access the values relating to that symbol (i.e. the values in the typeA column). If this makes no sense, read the chapters in Hadley's book (it's worth the effort)

Comment: Thank you! I'll invest some time in reading the refs you provided.